# Вызов функции из Kotlin файла в коде Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю проект(андроид приложение) и стало интересно, можно ли как-то вызвать функцию из Kotlin файла, в Java. Я имею следующий код на Java:

```java
package com.example.a8888;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.a8888.SumKt.sum_a;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int result;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        result = sum_a(5,3);
        textView.setText(result);

    }
}
```

И также функцию в Kotlin файле:

```kotlin
package com.example.a8888
fun sum_a(A:Int,B:Int): Int {
    var C:Int;
    C = A+B
    return C
}
```

И при компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import static com.example.a8888.SumKt.sum_a;
                               ^
  symbol:   class SumKt
  location: package com.example.a8888
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно устранить эту ошибку,буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы забыли поставить знак ";"

```
fun sum_a(A:Int,B:Int): Int {
    var C:Int;
    C = A+B;
    return C;
}
```

И второе, `textView.setText(result);` выдаст ошибку, result это int. Поменяйте на

```
textView.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

Comment: В Kotlin не нужны точки с запятой в конце строк.

Comment: Возможно, я сильно много с ним не работал. Но ошибка говорит, что пропущен какой-то символ в функции

Answer (score 0):

Если файл модуля на kotlin имеет имя SumKt.kt, то импортировать функцию из него нужно так (т.е. по сути при импорте к имени файла без учета расширения нужно добавить `Kt`):

```
import static com.company.a8888.SumKtKt.sum_a;
```

Либо переименовать файл просто в Sum.kt, тогда импорт как в вопросе будет работать.

См. [Вызов кода Kotlin из Java](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), раздел "Функции уровня пакета (Package-Level Functions)"